# Prohibit Duplicate Rows Inserted into Table

Tags: python, sql-server

Suppose I have a simple SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (
Model CHARACTER(10),
Brand CHARACTER(10)
)
```

Now, suppose I have inserted the following into the previously created table:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (Model, Brand) VALUES ('Thunderbird', 'Ford')
INSERT INTO TestTable (Model, Brand) VALUES ('Bronco', 'Ford')
```

How can I construct an `INSERT` statement that will not insert data already contained in the table?  The following `INSERT` statements should execute without resulting in duplicate rows:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (Model, Brand) VALUES ('Fairlane', 'Ford')
INSERT INTO TestTable (Model, Brand) VALUES ('Mustang', 'Ford')
INSERT INTO TestTable (Model, Brand) VALUES ('Thunderbird', 'Ford')
```

Ultimately, I would like to script this insertion via Python's `pypyodbc` library.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this for MySQL or SQLServer? These are two entirely different products.

Comment: SQLServer - sorry, MySQL tag has been removed.

Comment: Use [**MERGE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: Is the "Model" + "Brand" always supposed to be unique?  One option is to make a compound primary key... this forces uniqueness, and any attempt to insert duplicates would result in an error. This enforces data consistency at a database level.

Comment: @pmbAustin Having a primary key is good practice. But in this case, that return error and would rollback all the others insert too.

Comment: A compound primary key may be a good option - I'll look into it.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I would like to maintain all data inserted up to the duplicate data and, ideally, continue inserting data while ignoring any encountered duplicates.

Comment: you can use unique constraint on combination of two columns....If you want to prevent exceptions from bubbling up to the application, without making changes to the application, you can use an INSTEAD OF trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a SQL query to perform the insert, then you can use the following:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (Model, Brand) 
SELECT t.model, t.Brand
FROM (VALUES ('Thunderbird', 'Ford')) AS t(model, brand)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TestTable 
                  WHERE t.model = model AND t.brand = brand)
```

If a duplicate exists the `INSERT` is not executed because the `SELECT` returns no rows.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/SNY63840)